# No files matching the pattern were found: "'**/*.js'"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I downloaded expo project source code from github and tried to install node_module.
But I got following issue.

[error] No files matching the pattern were found: "'**/*.js'".
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.

My node version is 14.15.1
expo version: 4.0.8
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

and I will share my package.json file

```
{

    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "eject": "expo eject",
        "postinstall": "yarn prettier && yarn lint",
        "prettier": "npx prettier --write '**/*.js'",
        "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern \"!**/.*\" .",
        "lint:fix": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern \"!**/.*\" --fix ."
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.(js|jsx)": [
            "yarn prettier",
            "yarn lint:fix",
            "git add"
        ]
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "7.0.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "10.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.2.2",
        "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
        "expo": "^37.0.0",
        "expo-asset": "~6.0.0",
        "expo-constants": "~6.0.0",
        "expo-font": "~6.0.1",
        "expo-google-app-auth": "^6.0.0",
        "expo-image-picker": "~6.0.0",
        "expo-location": "~6.0.0",
        "expo-permissions": "~6.0.0",
        "mobx": "^4.3.1",
        "mobx-react": "^5.1.0",
        "mobx-state-tree": "^3.7.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "native-base": "^2.12.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "react": "16.6.0",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-native-design-utility": "^0.0.30",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~1.1.0",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^2.10.0",
        "react-native-webview": "~5.12.0",
        "react-navigation": "2.18.2",
        "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
        "eslint": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
        "husky": "^1.1.2",
        "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
        "schedule": "0.4.0"
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it works. You can try to overwrite your prettier configuration like this

```
"prettier": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts}\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous solution really worked. Сan also is used without quotes:

```
"prettier": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts}"
```